# Why do banks sometimes not withdraw their test deposits after linking accounts?

Tags: banking

When adding external accounts, banks will make two test deposits to the target bank between $0.01 and $1.00. To link accounts, the amounts at the target must be confirmed with the initial bank. Sometimes they will withdraw this amount, and sometimes they don't.

Why do they sometimes not withdraw this amount?

Answer (score 3):

It's not worth the effort - executing a transaction costs time and money,and if you get only back your 14 cent, why'd you care?

Same reason why some people don't pick up a penny - *not worth the effort*

Comment: What if instead of a penny, it was a few fractions of a penny, and you did it a couple million times?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon why does it say paper jam when there is no paper jam!?!

Comment: I'm not sure about the monetary cost argument. Could be true. But time certainly isn't a factor considering these verification deposits are all automated. They wouldn't have to spend the time to manually withdraw the amount after verification is complete.

Comment: This is purely speculative but since banks constantly link to each other through this method perhaps they have an agreement in place to tally the difference and pay in some fixed time instead of wasting money in transfers.